# Как использовать переменные класса для инициализации других переменных класса?

Tags: python

```py
class A:
    a = 42
    b = list(a for _ in range(1))
```

Почему этот код не работает?

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Технически, a - это не локальная и не глобальная переменная, поэтому обращение просто по имени не должно работать, только через `A.a` (но в данном случае не будет работать, потому что класс `A` еще не объявлен). Однако простые присваивания типа `b = a` почему-то работает, видимо не работает  именно вычисление полей из значений других полей класса.

Comment: @insolor в b = a есть же вычисление значение поля a

Comment: @Краб У вас там генераторное сокращение по факту используется, это как отдельную функцию вызвать получается. А в функции такие умолчания уже не работают, что `a` - это на самом деле `A.a`, нужно полностью писать. Это только сразу после `class` интерпретатор понимает сам, что `a` - это `A.a`, а в другой области видимости уже не понимает.

Comment: @CrazyElf на уровне класса не будет https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0f3w.png

Comment: @Краб b = a - это не вычисление, а просто присваивание

Comment: Как костыль, можно снаружи класса прописать `A.b = list(A.a for _ in range(1))`

Comment: @insolor А, я ядро не перезапустил, точно, ругается. Хм.

Comment: Короче, вот целая простыня на эту тему на английском СО: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933/8324991

Comment: @CrazyElf спс за ответ

Comment: @insolor то есть хочешь сказать что присваивание ничего не знает о правой части поэтому работает?

Comment: В общем, по поводу вычисления моя гипотеза не подтвердилась, потому что выражения типа `c = a + b` вполне работают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объяснение там [довольно сложное](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933/8324991), но можно сделать через лямбду (не совсем так, как в другом ответе):

```py
class A:
    a = 42
    b = (lambda a=a:[a for _ in range(1)])()
    print(a, b)
```

Вывод:

```
42 [42]
```

Если коротко, то у списковых, генераторных и прочих сокращений своя область видимости, там уже не работает умолчание, что `a` - это на самом деле `A.a`. При этом на `A.a` там тоже нельзя сослаться, поскольку класс `A` ещё в процессе определения. Но можно "пробросить" переменную через анонимную функцию `lambda` и тут же выполнить эту функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать отложенное вычисление (lazy evaluation) с помощью лямбда-функции, которая будет возвращать значение a при вызове

```
class A:
    a = 42
    b = [lambda: A.a for _ in range(1)]
```

Comment: Так содержимое b же другое теперь

Comment: у вас в выражении создания списка, но на момент создания списка переменная 'a' еще не была определена

Comment: Почему? Вон же она выше ^

Comment: в ошибке прямым текстом это написано что нет переменной 'a'

Comment: Но если сделать b = a то работает

Comment: ну я же говорю что переменна а не видна циклу в момент иницилизации
Я думаю что вам нужно залесть в документацию по работе с классами и болле подробно почитать почему так

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov Не будет ничего меняться в `b`, это если вы на список дадите ссылку и будете внутри списка что-то менять - тогда да. А если это обычное значение, то присваивание чего-то другого в `a` не повлияет на `b`.

Comment: В общем понятно что ничего не понятно ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov А вообще у вас в `A.b` теперь список с функцией внутри, это явно не то, что хотел автор )